# How To Generate hash value equivalent to node.js in php

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, hash

I have been facing a problem in my Project. I want to generate a hash which is equivalent to node.js hash value.
Here is my Node.js code

```
crypto.createHash('sha256').update('').digest('hex')
```

Which generates `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855`

And my PHP code is

```
$secret_key = hash('sha256', '', true);
$contentHash = hash_hmac('sha256', '', $secret_key);
```

Which generates `bfe4527091e7291c5b9a9359c579a97302ba3a7d969994f80a562db7bad4315c`

I want to generate same hash value though the platform is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want HMAC, you just want straight SHA256 in hex format:

```
$string = '';
$hash = hash('sha256', $string);
echo $hash;
```

Yields:

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```